# Wrap a new div element around specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I am struggling with this one.

How can I wrap a new `<div>` element around text that does not have any class or ID?

Below is the scenario:

```
<div class="ContentDiv">.....</div>

Share your knowledge. <a href="URL">Be the first to write a review »</a>
```

I need the new `div` to wrap around "`Share your knowledge. <a href="URL">Be the first to write a review »</a>`"

I have tried the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ContentDiv').each(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div class="NewDiv"></div>');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ContentDiv">.....</div>

Share your knowledge. <a href="URL">Be the first to write a review »</a>
```

but it is not working because it wraps around the `<a>` element only and leaves the text below it. I need the rest of the text in there as well.

Comment: Can you show us the full HTML code? What's the parent of the `"Share your... "`

Comment: But in your markup `div.ContentDiv` is not parent of `Share your knowledge. <a href="URL">Be the first to write a review »</a>`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get the next textnode after `.ContentDiv` and wrap that:

```
$('.ContentDiv').each(function() {
   $(this).next('a').add(this.nextSibling).wrapAll('<div class="NewDiv"></div>');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/PnjM9/3/)

Since jQuery does'nt really get textnodes, the native `nextSibling` should work.

Comment: You have `>>` at the end of that div instead of just `>`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - Oops, typo! fixed it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be including the `<a href="URL">Be the first to write a review »</a>`.

Comment: @j08691 - did'nt notice the point was to wrap both, but that's just a matter of adding them togheter and wrapping them.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can add a div after $('.ContentDiv') and then add the html to it.

```
$("<div id='new_div'></div").insertAfter($('.ContentDiv')).html("Share your knowledge. <a href='URL'>Be the first to write a review »</a>");
```